# Getting the value of LaunchArgument inside python Launch file

Tags: ros2, python, launch-file, ros2-launch

I've came across an interesting issue.

Is it possible to get the value of the LaunchArgument inside the python launch file?

Take the following scenario:

```
...
def generate_launch_description():

  input_topic_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(name="input_topic", default_value=TextSubstitution(text=default_topic))

  --> get the "input_topic" launch argument string here somehow <--


  return LaunchDescription([
    input_topic_arg,
    Node(
      package='demo_package',
      executable='demo_node',
      output='screen',
      parameters=[{"input_topic": LaunchConfiguration('input_topic')}]
  ])
```

I've went through the LaunchArgument source code and found that is impossible to get the value directly from the `input_topic_arg` variable as the **LaunchArgument** code passes its default directly into **LanchConfiguration**.

That leaves us with only one option and that is forcing the value out of the `LaunchConfiguration('input_topic')` object. This class has a `perform(LaunchContext)` function that is designed to return the parameter value, but it requires the **LaunchContext** which was used in the launch file.

So the question is: Given this is the way to get to the **LaunchArgument**, is there a way of getting the implicitly defined Context which has been used to construct **LaunchConfiguration**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accidentally stumbled upon an answer to this issue while reading the OpenVINS [docs](https://docs.openvins.com/gs-tutorial.html#gs-tutorial-ros2).

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, OpaqueFunction
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node

launch_args = [
    DeclareLaunchArgument(name='config', default_value='default', description='description'),
]

def launch_setup(context):
    config = LaunchConfiguration('config').perform(context) # Here you'll get the runtime config value

    node1 = Node(package = '...',
                 executable = '...',
                 parameters =[{'config': LaunchConfiguration('config')}])

    return [node1]

def generate_launch_description():
    opfunc = OpaqueFunction(function = launch_setup)
    ld = LaunchDescription(launch_args)
    ld.add_action(opfunc)
    return ld
```

Basically you need to create an [OpaqueFunction](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/rolling/launch/launch/actions/opaque_function.py) that recieves the correct runtime context -> This allows for correctly evaluating the `LaunchConfiguration.perform(Context)` function.

You can then act upon the runtime config value in whatever way you like.