# How to get launch parameter (LaunchConfiguration) value in string?

Tags: ros-humble, parameters, launch-file

I just want to have a log message with the parameter value, and I can't find how to.

```py
  return LaunchDescription([
    arg_i,
    LogInfo(msg=LaunchConfiguration('i')),  # this one has the value, but I want it in a string
    LogInfo(msg=f"i = '{ LaunchConfiguration('i') }'"),  # here I have the object string, not the param value
  ])
```

-> I don't want to use the *OpaqueFunction* to have my log.

In case this is not possible, I have another similar problem, I want to use the param value in a mathematical operation, and use the result as a node argument :

````py
i = LaunchConfiguration("i")

spawner = Node(
    package="ros_gz_sim",
    executable="create",
    arguments=[
        "-Y", str( int(i) * (math.pi/4)),
    ],
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the only way to get the `LaunchConfiguration` parameter value at runtime (not the default parameter value) is to use `OpaqueFunction`.

The problem is you need to get the right context used to build the LaunchDescription and as far as I know this is the only way to expose it.

A short example is [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104340/getting-the-value-of-launchargument-inside-python-launch-file).